# Первый запуск Ubuntu паралельно с виндовс 10 (try or install ubuntu) и зависает экран загрузки. Что делать?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Делал всё по инструкции:

1. Установил образ ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
2. Скачал rufus-4.4p.exe
3. С помощью rufus разложил образ на флешке
4. Отделил память 32г
5. Перезапускаю ноутбук и захожу по флешке
6. Выбираю (try or install ubuntu)
   После чего начинается запуск ubuntu проходит секунд 30 и загрузочный экран зависает

Пробовал нажимать на клавиши в итоге выяснил что пока все не зависло можно на f2 нажать и вот что увидел
[image: Последняя запись после зависания]

Comment: Попробуйте дождаться зависания и нажать Ctrl+Alt+F2 (или какую-нибудь другую F...). Что-нибудь происходит?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat При нажатии Ctrl+alt+f2 ( или какой-либо другой f...)ничего не происходит при зависании и даже до зависания . Работает на просто f2 или на f12(тоже самое что и f2) но до зависания

Comment: А при загрузке нет опции "try ubuntu (safe graphics)" или что-то такое? Если нет, я бы попробовал поменять rufus на что-то другое, а потом попробовал совершенно другой дистрибутив (manjaro какой-нибудь).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Есть такое но там также. Пробовал менять rufus на etcher, версии образа помоложе устанавливал, менял дистрибутивы, присматривался к обновлению bios(но у меня актуальный стоит)  - ничего из этого не помогает. Может у меня несовместимость с железом?

Comment: Угу, погуглите марку ноута на совместимость с линуксом. Сюда тоже напишите, может я найду. Еще флешку можно другую попробовать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Это Asus FX505DY? (FX505DY-BQ009T - серийный номер как я понимаю)

Comment: Хмм, нагуглил какие-то ошибки, но не такие как у вас. Попробуйте тут спросить: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Еще [вот тут](https://www.linux.org/threads/solved-encountering-some-trouble-installing-linux-on-asus-fx505dy.41857/) человеку помог какой-то флаг командной строки ядра (это в grub по какому-то хоткею редактируется), но у него ошибки другие. Можно попробовать.